# how can i prevent website's behavior event on the press of a key based on a condition using content scripts from an extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events, content-script

I have this extension where it allows user to make a list of notes, and it starts to watch the focused element's user input using content scripts, and if user activates an option in it, it will start the function.

```
let Notes // Declare the Notes variable outside the function to make it accessible globally

const createNoteListContainer = (notes) => {
  // Create a <div> element to hold the list of notes
  const focusedElement = document.activeElement
  const focusedElementRect = focusedElement.getBoundingClientRect()
  const noteListContainer = document.createElement('ul')
  noteListContainer.style.backgroundColor = 'white'
  noteListContainer.style.Color = 'black'
  noteListContainer.classList.add('note-list-container')
  noteListContainer.style.position = 'absolute'
  noteListContainer.style.zIndex = 9999
  noteListContainer.style.padding = '10px'
  noteListContainer.style.boxShadow = '0 3px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2)'
  noteListContainer.style.borderRadius = '10px'
  noteListContainer.style.listStyle = 'none'
  noteListContainer.style.paddingLeft = '0'
  noteListContainer.style.maxHeight = '180px'
  noteListContainer.style.width = `${focusedElement.clientWidth}px`
  noteListContainer.style.marginTop = '10px'
  noteListContainer.style.overflowY = 'auto'
  noteListContainer.style.overflowX = 'hidden'

  // Add the notes to the note list container
  notes.forEach((note) => {
    const noteItem = document.createElement('li')
    const noteTitle = document.createElement('h4')
    const noteBody = document.createElement('p')
    noteTitle.style.fontWeight = 'bolder'
    noteTitle.style.fontSize = '16px'
    noteTitle.style.color = 'black'
    noteBody.style.color = 'black'
    noteItem.style.minHeight = '60px'
    noteItem.style.cursor = 'pointer'
    noteItem.style.width = '100%'
    noteItem.style.background = '#fff'
    noteItem.style.borderBottom = '1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15)'
    noteItem.style.margin = '0 5px'
    noteItem.style.padding = '0 5px'
    noteItem.style.borderRadius = '3px'
    noteItem.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
      noteItem.style.background = '#f5f7f9'
    })
    noteItem.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
      noteItem.style.background = '#fff'
    })

    noteTitle.textContent = note.title
    noteBody.textContent = note.text
    noteItem.appendChild(noteTitle)
    noteItem.appendChild(noteBody)
    noteListContainer.appendChild(noteItem)
  })
  const distanceToBottom = getDistanceToBottomOfScreen(focusedElement)

  // Calculate the position based on the page height and focused element position
  const containerTop =
    distanceToBottom > 150
      ? focusedElementRect.top + focusedElement.clientHeight
      : focusedElementRect.bottom - 280
  noteListContainer.style.top = `${containerTop}px`
  noteListContainer.style.left = `${focusedElementRect.left}px`

  // Add the note list container to the document body
  document.body.appendChild(noteListContainer)
}
function getDistanceToBottomOfScreen(focusedElement) {
  // Get the bounding rectangle of the active element relative to the viewport
  const elementRect = focusedElement.getBoundingClientRect()

  // Get the viewport height
  const viewportHeight =
    window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight

  // Calculate the distance from the bottom of the active element to the bottom of the screen
  const distanceToBottom = viewportHeight - elementRect.bottom
  return distanceToBottom
}
const RenderNotesList = async () => {
  const focusedElement = document.activeElement
  if (focusedElement.parentNode.className.includes('ant-dropdown-trigger')) {
    return
  }
  const checkElement = document.querySelector('.note-list-container')
  if (checkElement) {
    checkElement.remove()
  }
  const result = await chrome.storage.local.get(['AdvancedMode', 'Notes'])
  if (result.AdvancedMode) {
    Notes = result.Notes
    const input = focusedElement.value
    const matchingNotes = input
      ? Notes.filter((oldNote) => {
          return oldNote.title.toUpperCase().startsWith(input.toUpperCase())
        })
      : []
    if (matchingNotes.length > 0) {
      createNoteListContainer(matchingNotes)
    } else {
      if (checkElement) {
        checkElement.remove()
      }
    }
  }
}

const handleKeyboardInput = async (event) => {
  if (
    event.keyCode === 13
  ) {
    handleEnterInput(event)
  } else {
    RenderNotesList()
  }
}
const handleEnterInput = (event) => {
  const focusedElement = document.activeElement
  const checkElement = document.querySelector('.note-list-container')

  if (checkElement) {
    event.preventDefault()
    focusedElement.value = checkElement.querySelector('li p').innerHTML
    focusedElement.dispatchEvent(
      new Event('input', {
        bubbles: true,
      }),
    )
    checkElement.parentNode.removeChild(checkElement)
  }
}
document.activeElement.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyboardInput, true)
```

my issue right now is that if the input (or textarea) does an action on the enter key being pressed (e.g: send a message or search for something) and there is an element with the class name " .note-list-container" the `event.preventDefault()`  doesn't stop the action, how do I make it stop the action?
i checked `event.cancelable` and its `true` I tried `event.stopPropagation()`  still didn't work, I tried changing the keydown to keyup and keypress and didn't work.

Comment: The site may be using event delegation (listening on document or window), so you need to attach the listener on `window` instead of document.activeElement, then check event.target ([example](/a/72085937)).